# chmod and chown changes list

Tags: chmod, chown

I was wondering if there is any way to view the changes history of commands chmod and chown in the whole system (folders and files in /). Is there any record log or any other way to get that information?

Comment: No, there's no log of these changes AFAIK.

Comment: notwithstanding `{/root,/home/*}/.*history`, which can be tampered with.

Comment: @DopeGhoti, there is possibility to use `chmod` in script or just to call `chmod` system call from program. But history files won't show even first case.

Comment: Hence the 'notwithstanding', as in "with the exception of".

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to get that information unless some mechanism is already in place to record it.

If your OS supports auditing, that would be a right tool to do it.

For example on Solaris, logging `chmod` usage would be done by enabling the [`fm` audit flag](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54776/audit-flags-5.html).

On Linux, [auditd](https://serverfault.com/questions/434483/monitor-or-log-directory-permission-changes) should do the trick, e.g.:

```
auditctl -a entry,always -S chmod
```